# Use LSP completion

Tags: autocompletion

I use `rust-analyzer` as LSP-server and `hrsh7th/nvim-compe` for autocomplete. As you can see on the pic, LSP providing some special completion for `default()` function, but how can I apply it to my code?

[image]

Comment: Press `<space>`?

Comment: It just adds a space symbol

Comment: What about `<tab>` or `<enter>`? If none of those works then perhaps your configuration isn't right. I don't know anything about the specific plugins you're using, though, so these are just suggestions based on how other autocompletions work. One thing you could try is disabling all other plugins and trying this in isolation...eliminate the possibility of some kind of conflict.

Comment: No, nothing works. I event commented whole my `init.vim`. <tab> just making a tabulation, <enter> just adding new line.
Maybe instead I should add something to `init.vim`?

Comment: Excluding your init.vim isn't a good idea. Look at the readme for the plugin. There's a whole bunch of config available. It looks like minimally you need to set `'completeopt'`. If you haven't, you should always read the readme and/or docs thoroughly before posting a question.

Comment: Perhaps control-y, if it’s using the standard complete menu

Comment: I have `completeopt=menuone,noselect` in `init.vim`.
And I read all readme for used plugins.
And `control-y` doesn't help too, it just reopens popup area

Comment: _I read all readme for used plugins._ Good to hear. Not everyone does so I have to ask.

Comment: I've rejected an edit from a Max because it appeared to add content as if they were the author. If there's multiple accounts with the same user, please let us know and we can merge them to avoid this issue.